# Pandas .describe() returns wrong column values in table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Look at the `gld_weight` column of figure 1. It is throwing off completely wrong values. The `btc_weight + gld_weight` should always adds up to 1. But why is the `gld_weight` column not corresponding to the returned row values when I used the describe function?

Figure 1:[image]

Figure 2:[image]

Figure 3:[image]

This is my source code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

assets = ['BTC-USD', 'GLD']
mydata = pd.DataFrame()

for asset in assets:
    mydata[asset] = wb.DataReader(asset, data_source='yahoo', start='2015-1-1')['Close']

cleandata = mydata.dropna()
log_returns = np.log(cleandata/cleandata.shift(1))

annual_log_returns = log_returns.mean() * 252 * 100
annual_log_returns

annual_cov = log_returns.cov() * 252
annual_cov
```

```
pfolio_returns = []
pfolio_volatility = []
btc_weight = []
gld_weight = []

for x in range(1000):
    weights = np.random.random(2)
    weights[0] = weights[0]/np.sum(weights)
    weights[1] = weights[1]/np.sum(weights)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    btc_weight.append(weights[0])
    gld_weight.append(weights[1])


    pfolio_returns.append(np.dot(annual_log_returns, weights))
    pfolio_volatility.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(annual_cov, weights))))

pfolio_returns
pfolio_volatility
```

```
npfolio_returns = np.array(pfolio_returns)
npfolio_volatility = np.array(pfolio_volatility)

new_portfolio = pd.DataFrame({
    'Returns': npfolio_returns,
    'Volatility': npfolio_volatility,
    'btc_weight': btc_weight,
    'gld_weight': gld_weight
})
```

Comment: What does (annual_log_returns) do? Its not defined atm!

Comment: It is just a formula to calculate the returns column.. but that is not the issue i am facing. I don't know why the describe.() function returns a wrong column value under 'gld_weight'

Comment: code error because of lack of information due to absence of annual_log_returns. Post what can be used at that place for proper function of the code. Same as for: annual_cov

Comment: as it appears the normalization of the values goes wrong... see my update 1 in my answer based on information from OP in comments.

Comment: Please upvote the answer Chang.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not 100% sure i got your question correctly, but an issue might be, that you are not reassigning the output to new variable, therefore not saving it.
Try to adjust your code in this matter:

```
new_portfolio = new_portfolio.sort_values(by="Returns")
```

Or turn inplace parameter to True - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 0):

***Short answer :***

> The issue at hand was found in the for-loop were the initial weight value normalization was done. How its fixed: see update 1 below in the answer.

Background to getting the solution:

At first glance the code of OP seemed to be in order and values in the arrays were fitted as expected by the requests OP made via the written codes. From testing it appeared that with `range(1000)` was asking for trouble because value-outcome oversight was lost due to the vast amount of "randomness" results. Especially as the question was written as a transformation issue. So x/y axis values mixing or some other kind of transformation error was hard to study.

1. To tackle this I used static values as can be seen for `annual_log_returns` and `annual_cov`.
2. Then I've locked all outputs for print so the values become locked in place and can't be changed further down the processing. .. it was possible that the `prints of code` changed during run-time because the arrays were not locked (also suggested by Pavel Klammert in his answer).
3. After commented feedback I've figured out what OP meant with "the values are wrong. I then focused on the method how the used values, to fill the arrays,  were created.

*The issue of **"throwing wrong values** was found :*

> The use of `weights[0] = weights[0]/np.sum(weights)` replaces the original list `weights[0]` value for new `weights[0]` which then serves as new input for `weights[1] = weights[1]/np.sum(weights)` and therefore sum = 1 is never reached.

4. The variable names `weights[0]` and `weights[1]` were then changed into 'a' and 'b' at two places directly after the creation of `weights` [0] and [1] values to prevent overwriting the initial `weights` values. Then the outcome is as "planned".

Problem solved.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pfolio_returns = []
pfolio_volatility = []
btc_weight = []
gld_weight = []

annual_log_returns = [0.69, 0.71]
annual_cov = 0.73

ranger = 5

for x in range(ranger):
    weights = np.random.random(2)
    weights[0] = weights[0]/np.sum(weights)
    weights[1] = weights[1]/np.sum(weights)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    btc_weight.append(weights[0])
    gld_weight.append(weights[1])


    pfolio_returns.append(np.dot(annual_log_returns, weights))
    pfolio_volatility.append(np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(annual_cov, weights))))

print (weights[0])
print (weights[1])
print (weights)

#print (pfolio_returns)
#print (pfolio_volatility)

npfolio_returns    = np.array(pfolio_returns)
npfolio_volatility = np.array(pfolio_volatility)

#df = pd.DataFrame(array, index = row_names, columns=colomn_names, dtype = dtype)

new_portfolio = pd.DataFrame({'Returns': npfolio_returns, 'Volatility': npfolio_volatility, 'btc_weight': btc_weight, 'gld_weight': gld_weight})

print (new_portfolio, '\n')

sort = new_portfolio.sort_values(by='Returns')

sort_max_gld_weight = sort.loc[ranger-1, 'gld_weight']

print ('Sort:\n', sort, '\n')

print ('sort max_gld_weight : "%s"\n' % sort_max_gld_weight)  # if "999" contains the highest gld_weight... but most cases its not!

sort_max_gld_weight = sort.max(axis=0)[3] # this returns colomn 4 'gld_weight' value.

print ('sort max_gld_weight : "%s"\n' % sort_max_gld_weight)  # this returns colomn 4 'gld_weight' value.

desc = new_portfolio.describe()

desc_max_gld_weight =desc.loc['max', 'gld_weight']

print ('Describe:\n', desc, '\n')
print ('desc max_gld_weight : "%s"\n' % desc_max_gld_weight)

max_val_gld = new_portfolio.loc[new_portfolio['gld_weight'] == sort_max_gld_weight]

print('max val gld:\n', max_val_gld, '\n')

locations = new_portfolio.loc[new_portfolio['gld_weight'] > 0.99]

print ('location:\n', locations)
```

Result can be for example:

```py
0.9779586087178525
0.02204139128214753
[0.97795861 0.02204139]
    Returns  Volatility  btc_weight  gld_weight
0  0.702820    0.627707    0.359024    0.640976
1  0.709807    0.846179    0.009670    0.990330
2  0.708724    0.801756    0.063786    0.936214
3  0.702010    0.616237    0.399496    0.600504
4  0.690441    0.835780    0.977959    0.022041 

Sort:
     Returns  Volatility  btc_weight  gld_weight
4  0.690441    0.835780    0.977959    0.022041
3  0.702010    0.616237    0.399496    0.600504
0  0.702820    0.627707    0.359024    0.640976
2  0.708724    0.801756    0.063786    0.936214
1  0.709807    0.846179    0.009670    0.990330 

sort max_gld_weight : "0.02204139128214753"

sort max_gld_weight : "0.9903300366638084"

Describe:
         Returns  Volatility  btc_weight  gld_weight
count  5.000000    5.000000    5.000000    5.000000
mean   0.702760    0.745532    0.361987    0.638013
std    0.007706    0.114057    0.385321    0.385321
min    0.690441    0.616237    0.009670    0.022041
25%    0.702010    0.627707    0.063786    0.600504
50%    0.702820    0.801756    0.359024    0.640976
75%    0.708724    0.835780    0.399496    0.936214
max    0.709807    0.846179    0.977959    0.990330 

desc max_gld_weight : "0.9903300366638084"

max val gld:
     Returns  Volatility  btc_weight  gld_weight
1  0.709807    0.846179     0.00967     0.99033 

loacation:
    Returns  Volatility  btc_weight  gld_weight
1  0.709807    0.846179     0.00967     0.99033
```

**Update 1 :**

```py
for x in range(ranger):
    weights = np.random.random(2)
    print (weights)
    a = weights[0]/np.sum(weights)  # see comments below.
    print (weights[0])
    b = weights[1]/np.sum(weights)  # see comments below.
    print (weights[1])
    print ('w0 + w1=', weights[0] + weights[1])
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
    btc_weight.append(a)
    gld_weight.append(b)
    print('a=', a, 'b=',b , 'a+b=', a+b)
```

The new output becomes for example:

```py
[0.37710183 0.72933416]
0.3771018292953062
0.7293341569809412
w0 + w1= 1.1064359862762474
a= 0.34082570882790686 b= 0.6591742911720931 a+b= 1.0
[0.09301326 0.05296838]
0.09301326441107827
0.05296838430180717
w0 + w1= 0.14598164871288544
a= 0.637157240181712 b= 0.3628427598182879 a+b= 1.0
[0.48501305 0.56078073]
0.48501305100305336
0.5607807281299131
w0 + w1= 1.0457937791329663
a= 0.46377503928658087 b= 0.5362249607134192 a+b= 1.0
[0.41271663 0.89734662]
0.4127166254704412
0.8973466186511199
w0 + w1= 1.3100632441215612
a= 0.31503564986069105 b= 0.6849643501393089 a+b= 1.0
[0.11854074 0.57862593]
0.11854073835784273
0.5786259314340823
w0 + w1= 0.697166669791925
a= 0.1700321364950252 b= 0.8299678635049749 a+b= 1.0
```

Results printed outside the for-loop:

```py
0.1700321364950252
0.8299678635049749
[0.17003214 0.82996786]
```

Comment: The problem is in your describe table. The btc_weight + gld_weight should ALWAYS be equal to 1. the row of 'mean' is correct. But you realise that from std downwards all the way to max, the 'gld_weight' and 'btc_weight' doesn't add up to 1.


```
weights = np.random.random(2)
    weights[0] = weights[0]/np.sum(weights)
    weights[1] = weights[1]/np.sum(weights)
    weights /= np.sum(weights)
```

^ Because of the above formula. btc_weight + gld_weight should be 1

Comment: euhm.... within the tables `max 'gld_weight' + min 'btc_weight' = 1` or `min 'gld_weight' + max 'btc_weight' = 1`. The `max 'gld_weight' + max 'btc_weight`' gets only 1 if both values each is 0.5 exact.

Comment: Your question is about something you see in the tables... your comment is about how you "create" your values for a particular "array"... that is a totally different question.